# Separate keyboard shortcuts for switching between keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, layout

I have a few language keyboard layouts installed in 12.04. I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard shortcut for switching between language layouts. Such switching method takes a lot of my time.

Is there any possibility to set up a different keyboard shortcut for each language keyboard layout?

For example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> (English layout),

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> (Polish layout),

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> (Italian layout), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: go to keyboard settings, click on "Shortcuts", and add "Custom shortcut". For each shortcut, add the respective command that chooses one layout. The commands are

```
setxkbmap -layout en
setxkbmap -layout pl
setxkbmap -layout it
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with January's solution is that it doesn't play nicely with Unity's indicator.

Below is a small python script that you can use instead of setxkbmap:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
from gi.repository import Gio

setting = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.input-sources")
keymaps = [keymap for (_, keymap) in setting['sources']]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='keymap_cycle', description='Cycle through a subset of enabled keymaps.')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
group.add_argument('-s', '--show', action='store_true', help='show available keymaps')
group.add_argument('-k', '--keymaps', default=','.join(keymaps), help='cycle through keymaps (default: %(default)s)')
arguments = parser.parse_args()


if arguments.show:
    print 'Available keymaps: %s' % ', '.join(keymaps)
else:
    cycle = arguments.keymaps.split(',')

    current_language = keymaps[setting['current']]

    try:
        current_cycle_index = cycle.index(current_language)
        desired_cycle_index = (current_cycle_index + 1) % len(cycle)
    except ValueError:
        desired_cycle_index = 0

    desired_language = cycle[desired_cycle_index]

    try:
        desired_language_index = keymaps.index(desired_language)
        setting['current'] = desired_language_index
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Save it to `$HOME/.local/bin` (or whatever other place you like), then `chmod +x` it.
Add all the keymaps you want via standard Ubuntu's keymap configuration screen.

Then the original question could be solved by binding a shortcut for each of the following commands:

```
keymap_cycle --keymap en
keymap_cycle --keymap pt
keymap_cycle --keymap it
```

But it can do even more! For example `keymap_cycle --keymap en,it` would cycle keymaps like this en->it->en->it... on each invocation.

To show all available keymaps you have added via Ubuntu's keymap configuration screen run `keymap_cycle --show`.

Kudos to @bjonen and his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/439112) for the gsettings magic insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsettings command with custom shortcuts. Read more details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/984981/6193