# Switch different language pairs with separate key combinations

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I use 3 different languages on my laptop, but most of time I need only 2 of them, so switching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is quite annoying. Is there a way to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> **for 2 languages** and have some **special combination** to temporarily **switch to the 3rd one**?

**Note**: there's very similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194787/separate-keyboard-shortcuts-for-switching-between-keyboard-layouts), but in my question I'd like to make emphasis on switching between 2 languages with normal key combination.

Answer (score 4):

Remove languages from keyboard layout

Then From Dash choose **keyboard settings** and then click on **shortcuts** then add **custom shortcut**

choose a name and command similar to this

```
setxkbmap -layout en
```

[image]

Then click on the "Disabled " on the right to make you shortcut lets say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Do it again for other languages you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said in my "note", I'm looking for a way to **switch between 2 languages with normal key combination**. E.g. I'd like to use Ctrl-Shift to switch between Lang1 and Lang2 and use, say, Alt-Shift to turn Lang3 on and off.

Comment: you can do that also with answer above. Remove the third unused language from keyboard layout so you can use ctrl-shift with lang1 and lang2. Then create a shortcut for the third with the above answer. so you can user ctrl-alt for switching between lang1 and lang2 and the created shortcut for lang3

Comment: Check the updated asnwer

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. First of all, Alt+Shift doesn't have effect at all (maybe reserved combination or something like that), so I used Alt+Alt R (left and right Alt keys). After setting, when I pressed them for the first time it really switched layout... but it also broke Ctrl-Shift combination! That is, I had only one layout (Lang3) left, and to get Lang1 and Lang2 back I had to reboot the whole system. Also, in "Keyboard Layout" settings Ctrl+Shift is shown as active, and in layout list there are still Lang1 and Lang2, and nothing about currently active Lang3.

Comment: ok then you should make a shortcut for each layout as prposed before. I think this is the only solution(maybe not)

Comment: For me it worked, but I had to use `en_US` instead of `en` (`setxkbmap -layout en_US`).