# How do I change keyboards from the command line?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

How I change keyboard layouts from the command-line?  For example, I want to switch from English to Hebrew.  I'm able to do it from lightdm with the little icon in the corner of my screen.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From terminal

English to Hebrew and vise versa with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us,il
```

You can see all locale alias with this command

```
cat /etc/locale.alias
```

More info about setxkbmap in manual

```
man setxkbmap
```

Comment: Information in how to set it on boot: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching

Comment: How do you find the Dvorak keyboard using this? `/etc/locale.alias` seems to contain a list of locales (languages), not keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 70):

You can find all the different keymaps in the following locations:

```
/usr/share/keymaps/i386/
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

> To change the keyboard layout (e.g. to Spanish) in the Linux command
>   line, type the following command:
>
> ```
> loadkeys es
> ```

For X:

> ```
> setxkbmap es
> ```
>
> To make these changes system wide, assuming you’re using Ubuntu, you
>   can use the following:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
> ```

Comment: This has effect on tty1, tty2, etc, but no effect in X.  I want to do it in X, the same way that the keyboard switcher in lightdm works.

Comment: I added a command in the answer, was this what you were looking for?

Comment: YES!  Thanks.  Also, can you update your answer to mention loadkeys, spelled with an 's'?

Comment: yep I will, and no thanks. Just mark as solved so everyone knows.

Comment: for redhat users, following are the valuable pieces: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and `setxkbmap es`

Comment: Be careful with the `loadkeys` command. I loaded Russian keys, and was unable to return to latin alphabet in the gnome-terminal, before I copy-pasted the letters 'us' with the mouse.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Wayland in Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Not all that surprising, it is specific for X.

Answer (score 14):

### Ubuntu 13.10 or Later

This works better then setxkbmap with Gnome/Unity keyboard layout indicator.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

0 is the layout index (0 default or top layout). Layouts indexed starting from 0.

For easy use, create an alias.

Comment: This answer is superior because it actually changes the indicator. Just what I've been looking for.

Comment: thanks. used your answer also here: https://askubuntu.com/a/984981/6193

Comment: This doens't work on GNOME 3.26. It says "This key is deprecated and ignored".

Comment: @hugomg, right now I don't have access yet to newer gnome. but you may try using `dconf-editor` tool and check `/org/gnome/desktop/`. they may just rename it.

Comment: if you're using gnome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 23.04. It seems to be set to `0` always.

Answer (score 11):

```
setxkbmap us,il -option "lv3:ralt_alt,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

this command enable you toggle between English and Hebrew only through by <kbd>right alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and rescue you from <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be no standard CLI tool, but [**xkb-switch**](https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch) is a small open-source tool to do the job. Just tested it with Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and it works flawelessly.

```
$ xkb-switch       # display current group
ua
$ xkb-switch -l    # list groups
us
ua
$ xkb-switch -s us # switch to a named group
$
```

This looks better than the other solutions because `setxkbmap <name>` ruins all options, and `setxkbmap -layout <name>`, while it preserves the options, it still fails to change the taskbar indicator nor the `grp_led` if set.

---

#### Caveat

If your `~/.config/kxkbrc` uses `LayoutLoopCount` (e.g. it is set to less than the total number of layouts listed in `LayoutList`), like this:

```
LayoutList=us,ua,th,de
LayoutLoopCount=2
Options=grp_led:scroll,grp:rwin_switch,compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,
        nbsp:level2,grp:rctrl_toggle,misc:typo
```

then `xkb-switch` would only let you switch between the layouts in current group.

---

#### Invoke at screen lock

I noticed your comment:

> Right before my screensaver turns on, I want to switch to English so that it will be easy to type my password when I get back in.

This was precisely my goal, so here's the answer:
To do that, you only need wrap it into a script hooking to `dbus-monitor` like discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28181/190768).

Answer (score 6):

Using **`gsettings`** in 18.04+ with Gnome, you can both add keyboard layouts and switch between them from the command line **or** from the keyboard layout switcher on the desktop.

1. Present keyboard layouts and options:

   ```
   $ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources false
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options ['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window false
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current uint32 1
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources @a(ss) []
   org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'es'), ('xkb', 'no')]
   ```
2. Adding keyboard layouts:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'no'),('xkb','gr')]"
   $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
   [('xkb', 'es'), ('xkb', 'no'), ('xkb', 'gr')]
   ```
3. Changing the current keyboard layout from the command line:

   ```
   $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
   ```

   As we now have 3 different languages, we have three choices from 0 to 2, with 1 being Spanish, 2 being Norwegian and 3 being Greek. Thus, setting *current* to 1 above makes Norwegian the current keyboard layout.
4. Listing all possible keyboard layouts:

   ```
   cat //usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
   ```
5. Changing the keyboard layout with a keyboard shortcut:

   A keyboard shortcut is preconfigured for changing the keyboard layout. The present shortcut:

   ```
   $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source
   ['<Super>space']
   ```

A new shortcut can be set by using `gsetting set`, but take care not to use a shortcut that is already in use. To list all shortcuts in use:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Super>h']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left ['<Super><Shift>Left']
...
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, kudos for this.

Comment: This part doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 23.04 with Wayland: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1`

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 18.04 + Gnome the other answers did not work for me, but this did:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
--method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
 "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

The argument in "inputSources[0]" is the index of the keyboard layout, the same as for gsettings solution.

Found it on [linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449475/179975).

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't work for GNOME >= 41. See the comments in that answer.

Comment: @Flimm For Gnome >= 41, eg Ubuntu 22, I have [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428946/569579)

Comment: Thanks. Small nit-pick, there is to such thing as "Ubuntu 22", you either meant "Ubuntu 22.04" (released in April 2022) or "Ubuntu 22.10" (released in October 2022). The version numbers are confusing, but they refer to the year and month of the date of release.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the best and most stable combination of `xkb-switch`, `setxkbmap` and `ibus`. IBus allows pinyin input and `xkb-switch` is stable, while `setxkbmap` returns back set of keyboard layouts.

This is important when switching directly to a language, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>4</kbd>. Why not using only IBus? It gets stuck all the time because it requires a restart to bring keyboard layouts back to life after switching to non-latin keyboard layout. At least in FireFox, see [I need to exit and restart ibus-daemon to make ibus-chewing work. #2319](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2319).

Disclaimer: Tested on OpenSuse Leap 15.3 xfce4 and [`xkb-switch`](https://github.com/grwlf/xkb-switch) is compiled from source

To make this work you should make script files with those commands and assign keyboard shortcuts to run them. Also you might want to disable Alt+Shift shortcut in keyboard switch settings to remove unexpected behavior.

So, here are my set of commands:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - switch to English:

```
killall ibus-daemon
setxkbmap us,ru,pt
xkb-switch -s us
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - switch to Russian:

```
killall ibus-daemon
setxkbmap us,ru,pt
xkb-switch -s ru
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> - switch to Chinese Mandarin Pinyin:

```
ibus-daemon -d
ibus reset-config
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general preload-engines "['libpinyin']"
setxkbmap us,ru,pt
xkb-switch -s us
ibus engine libpinyin
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> - switch to Portugese:

```
killall ibus-daemon
setxkbmap us,ru,pt
xkb-switch -s pt
```

Also assign the following script to run on system autostart.

```
killall ibus-daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the other answers in to this question, you'll soon realize:  it's pretty hard to achieve in Ubuntu, as none of the methods that you could Google works properly.

- The `setxkbmap` doesn't play nice with the GNOME Shell.
- The `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore
- The `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …` is also deprecated due to security implications.

That's why, I've made my own GNOME Shell Extension and I'm sharing it with the world: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".

Answer (score 0):

It may look hacky but it works like a charm:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout ru,us
setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

To force switch:

```
setxkbmap -layout ru && setxkbmap -layout us && setxkbmap -layout us,ru
```

Answer (score 0):

Still valid with Ubuntu 22.04 in virtualbox 7.0:

Even when choosing the correct keyboard at install, you get a qwerty keyboard by default at the console.
To get rid of it type this for eg Belgian:

```
loadkeys be
```

Then save the value to keep it permanent

```
vi /etc/default/keyboard
/XKBLAYOUT
/us
cwbe<ESC>
ZZ
```

as found in this post: [How to permanently configure keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

Just out of curiosity, why would you do that ? Why would you open a terminal and they type a command to switch your keyboard layout when you can do so by a simple keyboard shortcut ! Assuming you use Ubuntu , it goes as `Windows` + `Space`

Comment: This appears to be more of a comment and less of an answer.

Comment: Right before my screensaver turns on, I want to switch to English so that it will be easy to type my password when I get back in.

Comment: also it is useful for making custom keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: This does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 on a virtualbox.