# How to permanently configure keyboard

Tags: keyboard, configuration

I use a Turkish keyboard which I have converted to English (Ubuntu server 12.04). My problem is that the single quote is not present on the keyboard but is instead represent by a comma in midair. To fix this I use the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

The problem is each time I shutdown, changes are reverted thus every time I start the system, I have to type that command. I was thinking of making it a cronjob but I`m sure there can be another way to make the changes permanent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` will change your keyboardlayout just for this session.

go for `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard` there you can change your keyboard settings.

Find the line :

```
XKBLAYOUT="xx"
```

You can change `layout` and `kboptions` as well as your `model` and the `kbvariant`.

Just put in `tr` for Turkish

[image: Keyboard File]

on older ubuntu versions you could go for `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and make permanently changes here. but for server 12.04 I guess it should be in the keyboard file.

Comment: This does not work by ubuntu server 14.04. I replaced the "us" with "hu" (Hungarian), but after reboot I still have English layout instead of Hungarian. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` worked for me, and it is permanent, I have Hungarian layout after reboot.

Comment: how can i get the values to put into these fields that are reconfigured by the 'keyboard-configuration' ? My keyboard turns british after reboots

Answer (score 11):

The keyboard settings are stored in /etc/default/keyboard file. It's provided by the keyboard-configuration package, and other packages use this information in order to configure the keyboard on the console or in X Window System.

You can change your keyboard settings using:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
service keyboard-setup restart
```

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard)

Comment: This was it! I choose 104 key layout for my keyboard and after choosing the defaults after that, my keyboard is back to normal again. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

To change it permanently via the terminal run this:

For US:

```
L='us' && sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=\"\w*"/XKBLAYOUT=\"'$L'\"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

For French:

```
L='fr' && sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=\"\w*"/XKBLAYOUT=\"'$L'\"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

For German:

```
L='de' && sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT=\"\w*"/XKBLAYOUT=\"'$L'\"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

and so on...

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

---

To change it temporarily you can use `setxkbmap mylayout`...

```
# US
setxkbmap us
# French
setxkbmap fr
# German
setxkbmap de
```

In terminal mode, you need to use `loadkeys` instead of `setxkbmap`

```
# US
loadkeys us
# French
loadkeys fr
# German
loadkeys de
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem since last year and i was everytime setting the keyboard layout when starting the system. I tried all methods but none helped except one which i found helped me :)

- Go > Applications > System tools > Preferences > Startup Application
- Add new
- **Name**: Default Keylayout
- **Command**:  setxkbmap us
- Save

Restart the system :)

Comment: Probably the easiest solution. Also worked for my Belgium azerty keyboard using  'setxkbmap be', for which I was struggling (because it's a slight variation of the French keyboard and Ubuntu seems a bit lost trying to recognize it)

Answer (score 2):

For console-only instances e.g. servers, you should install the `console-data` package with `apt-get install console-data` and then set it up with `dpkg-reconfigure console-data`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above on an Ubuntu 16.04 and only the temporary solution `setxkbmap xx` did it for me so I manually included it in the .bashrc profile: `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` and then type `setxkbmap xx`replacing xx with yor language code

Comment: Only answer that worked for me in debian/bunsenlabs/openbox.