# English menus, but German keyboard setting

Tags: language-support, locale

every time I start my computer up, the English keyboard setting is active, and I have to change back to the German (Switzerland) one.

I want to keep my Computer as English as possible (e.g. English menus), but with a permanently active German (Swiss) keyboard setting.

How can I do that?

Comment: please see my answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard/342099#342099  let me know if this helped u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272 (Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04 and 14.10 seems plagued by a series of multi-layout keyboard bugs. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 which is one of the hottest bugs in launchpad).

There are a couple of workarounds that seem to work; at least they work for me. Basically you issue from a terminal

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.general use-system-keyboard-layout false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

and then disable IBus in Settings -> Language support:

[image: Settings -> Language support]

It works for me, although you loose some function (for example, ctrl+shif+u unicode direct input).

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly!

I do not use ctrl-schift-u Unicode input anyway, so...

Answer (score 1):

Access the Dash, search for an application named "Text Entry" and start it up. In it you will be presented with a selection box entitled "Input sources to use:"; it lists all the keyboard mappings presently available in your system. In your case it is probably listing *English* and *German (Switzerland)*.

You can turn the German mapping the default in two ways:

1. using the "arrow up" button to move the German mapping to the top.
2. using the "minus" button to remove all mappings except German.

These buttons are signalled in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I have applied this, and German (Switzerland) is already at the top of this list. But still after every boot, the English keyboard layout is active... :/ 

Not a big problem anyway, but it's nevertheless nagging.