# shift + left alt not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I´m currently unable to make special characters using <kbd>left alt</kbd> on my MacBook Pro, Swedish keyboard (running for an external SSD, Ubuntu 14.04).

For example, if i try to make a pair of curly brackets using <kbd>left alt</kbd>,  i.e. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>8 and 9</kbd> nothing happens - it only works using <kbd>right alt</kbd>. However, <kbd>left alt</kbd> do work with other keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I have tried different keyboard layouts and to look for suitable options in `system preferences -> text entry`. I did notice that there are similar questions to mine, but they involve special characters using <kbd>left ctrl</kbd><kbd>left alt</kbd>, and not <kbd>left shift</kbd><kbd>left alt</kbd>. Is it a simple fix to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I had to do (Taken from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032691/145907)):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

- Choose the 104-key layout (thanks to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1216499/is-my-keyboard-generic-101-key-pc-or-generic-105-key-pc-intl-or-what))
- Use the default options for the rest

`sudo service keyboard-setup restart`

And that was it! Now my keyboard's <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> combination works again! More specifically, the ones on the left of the keyboard.

---

In case you were curious, my laptop is a Lenovo G510, and I am running Ubuntu 16.04 at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Characters as `{} [] ~ @ ² ³ µ` are not selected by the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> key combination (i.e. the `{` char) but by <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. The right  key on PC/AT keyboard has a special meaning, it is the same as pressing <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys - that is why it is inscriped <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

So for my understanding it is all fine with your keyboard.