# “English (US, International with dead keys)” missing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 18.04

I was able to find and configure the *English (US, International with dead keys)* keyboard on every version of Ubuntu so far, but I really couldn't find it on the new 18.04. Did they remove it completely?

[image: Input sources screenshot]

I am able to get the same effect if I execute the following command on terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

However, I am having trouble executing this command on startup and, anyway, I wish I was able to configure the keyboard directly.

Any tips?

Comment: It's there. Not clear to me what made you think otherwise.

Comment: I think you might need to edit the default settings file, see [How to permanently configure keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Same problem here with 18.04. Layout "german without deadkeys" and even Macintosh-keyboard-layout and so on not shown

Comment: A question to both AndreG and @amDude1848: Which locales have been generated on your system? Can you please show us the output of the terminal command `locale -a`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson This is a bit longer list. i have installed german and english language packs, but mostly using the german one: C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_IT.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: @amDude1848: Thanks. Considering that you seem to have all the German locales, the _German (no dead keys)_ layout ought to be shown.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for checking this out. Unfortunatelly the keyboard-layouts are missed in the menu. :-(

Comment: @amDude1848: They are in sub menus of _German_ or _German (Germany)_.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Omg, i found them by searching for some sub-menus. I am not sure why i did not found them earlier. I think i simply did not clicked on "German" again at the bottom menu ("input-sources"). Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

Comment: @amDude1848: It was easier in Unity. Just one long list, from where you could look up any input source directly. The new GUI confuses quite a few users.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thats right, this is hidden like hell. I will try to post an answer for AndreG. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Wow, I never thought about selecting the language so I've never seen the sub menu. Indeed it used to be all in a long list in the past. Well, I guess it is more organized this way.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The menu with the keyboard-layouts is bit hidden in Gnome. To set your keyboard-layout open language-settings and click the Plus-Button(+) at the bottom left. Than add your language again and after that the sub-menu with the keyboard-layouts will open.

The full path to reaching the option is: Settings app -> Region & Language -> Click the + icon in Input Sources -> Select your main language -> Select the keyboard layout from the sub-menu

Comment: And only to make this answer even more complete. The full path to reaching the option is: Settings app -> Region & Language -> Click the + icon in Input Sources -> Select your main language -> Select the keyboard layout from the sub-menu.

Comment: Despite this, I can still not see the "English (US, International with dead keys)" in Ubuntu 18.04

I keep ending up with the same selection as the one shown in the question above.

Comment: Wow, that's just crazy. You cannot CHANGE already existing layout, you have to remove and create it again...

Comment: For me, apart from what's outlined above, it also took a restart to make the deadkeys work properly. I'm using UK intl keyboard. Just in case if anyone attempts this but doesn't see the results :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem in XFCE under 18.04. Under Settings > Keyboard, Layout tab, after clicking + Add, I could only find a couple variants of English. Then (duh!) I noticed that this was a hierarchical list, with a little triangle in front of "English (US)". Click on that arrow, and all the variants appear underneath. It was strange that I didn't find this little hint in over an hour of searching, which is why I'm posting it here for the next person who doesn't notice the triangle.

Comment: I saw no triangle, but selecting English (US) makes the entry expand into a variety of further options, including the "English (IS, intl., with dead keys" that I needed.

Comment: Same "duh!" here. Tks for sharing.