# ubuntu 18.04 keyboard layout messed up after update

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, xps

I have recently performed an update on my Dell XPS 15.

Before the update, the keyboard layout as much as the keyboard shortcuts were working: my German keyboard was recognized, I could switch between keyboard layouts using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and the Keyboard Shortcuts using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key defined in Settings->Devices->Keyboard were working.

After the update, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key alone is switching between different Keyboard layouts and NONE tested Keyboard Shortcuts using the <kbd>Super</kbd> are working including those that I erased and defined again. Hence, I can not switch between the keyboard layouts using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

The responsible update seems to be one of the following (from /var/log/apt/history.log)

```
Start-Date: 2018-07-31  01:09:58
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Upgrade: papirus-icon-theme:amd64 (20180723-2516+pkg18~ubuntu18.04.1, 20180728-2528+pkg18~ubuntu18.04.1), console-setup-linux:amd64 (1.178ubuntu2.2, 1.178ubuntu2.3), console-setup:amd64 (1.178ubuntu2.2, 1.178ubuntu2.3), keyboard-configuration:amd64 (1.178ubuntu2.2, 1.178ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2018-07-31  01:10:24

Start-Date: 2018-07-31  09:50:32
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.142'
Install: hunspell-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.0.3-3), hunspell-en-za:amd64 (1:6.0.3-3), hyphen-en-ca:amd64 (0.10), hyphen-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.0.3-3), libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-l10n-en-za:amd64 (1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1), thunderbird-locale-en-gb:amd64 (1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), mythes-en-au:amd64 (2.1-5.4), libreoffice-help-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1), hunspell-en-au:amd64 (1:2017.08.24), hunspell-en-ca:amd64 (1:2017.08.24)
End-Date: 2018-07-31  09:50:35
```

Attempted solution:
As described here [How to permanently configure keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard) I executed

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Selecting "keyboard model: Dell Inspiron 6000/8000 laptop, origin of the keyboard: German, keyboard layout: German, function as AltGr " The default..., No compose key, and no key for X server termination"
gives

```
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowmacron"
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
```

After this, everything is working as before the update as described above.

**Problem** Suprisingly (update-initramfs was called and it was mentioned in the link that this would stick) the changes disappear after reboot. In addition, if I add or remove a keyboard layout via Settings->Region&Language I am also back with my old problems.

I also tried changing /etc/default/keyboard by hand which does not change anything.

Commands and output as suggested by Gunnar Hjalmarsson :

1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

   ```
   XKBLAYOUT="de"
   BACKSPACE="guess"
   XKBVARIANT=""
   XKBMODEL="inspiron"
   XKBOPTIONS=""
   ```
2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

   ```
   GLib-GIO-Message: 10:49:09.149: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  
   Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
   @as []
   ```
3. `setxkbmap -query -v 10`

   ```
   Setting verbose level to 10
   locale is C
   Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
   Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
   Success.
   Applied rules from evdev:
   rules:      evdev
   model:      inspiron
   layout:     de,us,us
   variant:    ,,
   options:    grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll
   Trying to build keymap using the following components:
   keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
   types:      complete
   compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
   symbols:    pc+de+us:2+us:3+inet(evdev)+group(lwin_toggle)
   geometry:   pc(pc104)
   rules:      evdev
   model:      inspiron
   layout:     de,us,us
   variant:    ,,
   options:    grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll
   ```

On checking whether dconf database might be corrupted via

```
cd ~/.config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

and re-login, I can change the Keyboard shortcuts under Settings->Devices->Keyboard and I can switch between layouts via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Everything still works after reboot. Obviously all my settings are gone with this approach and I would need to reinstall all my gnome extensions etc. Is there a way to fix the dconf database (which parameters to change)?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of these commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` 3. `setxkbmap -query -v 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fully resolve the issue by changing dconf as follows:
Install dconf editor:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open the editor in command line by

```
dconf-editor
```

Then go to

```
/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
```

Here I turned off option "Use default value"

This resolved all issues described above. Thanks to @Gunnar Hjalmarsson for pointing me to dconf.
This link was helpful for [dconf](https://winaero.com/blog/single-key-shortcut-change-keyboard-layout-gnome-3/) with a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the `setxkbmap` command that the option `grp:lwin_toggle` is set, which probably explains why only pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key switches layout. At the same time `/etc/default/keyboard` does not include any `XKBOPTIONS`, neither does the desktop setting (the `gsettings` command).

Based on that info, a reboot should fix it.

But then you say that adding/removing some layout from *Region & Language* messes it up. I notice a warning message when you run the `gsettings` command, and wonder if your dconf database might be corrupted. To find out, you may want to try these commands:

```
cd ~/.config/dconf
mv user user.bak
```

and relogin.

Comment: Thanks you for all your help! Do you  know whether it is possible to fix the config file?

Comment: @dgruending: Since you ask, did that renaming idea help? I'm not aware of a way to fix a corrupted dconf database. (Not saying it can't be done.)

Comment: I edited the question - the keyboard problem seems to be gone, but with the renaming approach I will have to reinstall gnome extensions, background and whatever else is stored in that file. So your answer solves the basic issue -> accepted

Comment: @dgruending: You may want to ask a separate question about how to fix the database. Otherwise few will see that part of your question.