# Language changes constantly in application input

Tags: 16.04, xps, input-language

Something in my Ubuntu 16.04 broke with my keyboard text input. In input fields of different programs (firefox, thunderbird, sublime), the keyboard input changes to something unknown the moment I use the shift key or a letter key.

Only the following keys return a letter when pressing the keys of the qwertz (german) keyboard:

```
wzü+
fjöä#
<n,.-
```

If I switch the application, or press "control+o" in sublime, I somehow get back to the normal "de" language settings. But if I again use shift, it breaks again and returns the garbage you see above.

System:
Dell XPS Developer Edition (9360) with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Here a screenshot of the text-related UI of Ubuntu & a bit of dmesg.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

If it doesn't work permanently, try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/342099/666758) solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, it did not work. But it seems to go deeper. I saw that not every application does have this problem (e.g. chromium). My guess is that something in the OS got messed up and before I fixed it, some applications I used during that time got mixed up. Those applications I did not start with the OS fixed do not seem to show the problems. Once I am certain what the problem is, I will write a reply.