# VirtualBox Setup UBUNTU 18LTS

Tags: virtualbox

I've recently upgraded my install of VirtualBox to 5.2.28, and while trying to reconfigure the VM's I find data entered into any field turns into gibberish.  For arguments sake, I type in 23 and the field becomes 0- which of course isn't valid.  The rest of the keyboard is similarly affected.

VirtualBox is the only thing affected by this problem. The original 14.04LTS install worked without a problem, and upgrade to 5.2.x broke it. The default install for 18.04LTS is also broken the same way at 5.2.18

Never seen anything like it before, any ideas?

A[image]

In case this helps identify the current mapping, qwerty comes out as 4c.gvn

EDIT: Well its still going on, not only that, but a fresh install of 18LTS actually gives me the same result.

Comment: Can you post a higher resolution screen snippet? I suggest using windows "snipping tool"

Comment: theres nothing in it except the VB startup window.

Comment: what brand and model  of keyboard is it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong keyboard layout. Open your launcher and search for keyboard layout. From there you should be able to add your keyboards layout to the list. You should set it as the default keyboard.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

[Incorrect keyboard mapping on Ubuntu under VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/422154/incorrect-keyboard-mapping-on-ubuntu-under-virtualbox)

---

**Edit:**

If you only have CLI than you can try

```
# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
# service keyboard-setup restart
```

When you run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` you should get a prompt for what keyboard layout you have/want, follow the prompts.

Source: [Debian Keyboard configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard)

From that I have seen this works for people using 14.04 though some say they had to use `sudo` when running it.

more information can be found here: [how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard)

Comment: whats a launcher? I don't see any kb mapping/layout options in VB

Comment: For what its worth, this is running under VNC. It opens with a console, and VB and that's it.

Comment: @A.Adverse I've added some images that I hope help clear things up for you.

Comment: Thanks for the images, is there some way to do this from CLI the server has no GUI.  VirtualBox is only running in a VNC session.

Comment: The image I've added shows my VNC desktop.  Until a recent "upgrade" it used to open a console as well.

Comment: @A.Adverse Ah ok CLI only. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This particular server is on 14.04.6

Comment: @A.Adverse I've edited my answer to include a CLI section. If this works for you please accept and upvote my answer. If it does not, let me know I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Odd I don't see any "result" from it... however off to see if did anything. No change, still gibberish. I haven't read your extra info yet though

Comment: /etc/default/keyboard is showing pc105 and US for model and layout, and re running dpkg-reconfigure isn't making any change. Even after running
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change 
for good measure

Comment: Anyone else with any ideas?  Its like VNC or VirtualBox is picking up the wrong keyboard from the system?

Comment: @A.Adverse ok some things to try, turn on the onscreen keyboard see if the layout looks right of if there is a mismatch with what you are using. https://ccm.net/faq/35051-enable-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-ubuntu

Comment: @A.Adverse Also, see if you can change the language to something else (french maybe). press some keys (ones that are give weird outputs) before you do so, note the result, then change the keyboard language, then press the same keys and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Ok, no idea how to turn on a virtual keyboard, I did try changing the settings to DE for german, but also no change.

Comment: following your link above at the moment, not sure it'll make much difference I don't have a full X install.  On the server there is NO keyboard, my local keyboard is an Apple KB.  

No X keyboard found. WARNING: OnboardGtk: vk :XkbGetKeyboard failed. 

All keys have ? on them.

Comment: oh right, sorry I forgot you were running a server version.  there may still be a way to do a onscreen keyboard if you connect to it "remotely" but that link is not going to be helpful.

Comment: @A.Adverse Ok, so this might be a bug. There is a possible 
 work around in the bug report  that may be worth a try. But it didn’t 
 work for another user. they do have a bit of a different setup. https://bugs.launchpad.net/onboard/+bug/1001736

Comment: I can't find an xorg.conf, a du -a turns up a /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d but I can't find anything useful in there.  The man page mentions an /etc/xorg.conf but creating one, and putting the entries in it, doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Help..........!

Comment: The default install from 14.04:LTS worked perfectly, as soon as it was "upgraded" it failed with this problem. The default install for 18.04LTS has the same keyboard problem.