# I can't figure out my keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am trying to change my keyboard lauout language to Lithuanian but then it does not change it still writes with the numbers not the Lithuanian letters.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` type this in the Terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T` brings your terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/

Comment: Please explain better how you changed it. Did you add Lithuanian in _Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources_, or did you do it some other way?

Comment: I added it in the settings Language and region

Comment: @ŽymantasRastenis: Ok. If you added it, then you should have at least two input languages in the list. Do you see an input source menu in the top panel? You should be able to make Lithuanian the active language via that menu.