# Keyboard changing special keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just installed standard Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as a second OS in my old PC, and can't seem to make the keyboard to work as expected.

Whenever I press the [ctrl-L] [win] [alt] [alt-gr] [ctrl-R] or [shift-R] the system thinks I'm pressing [shift-L].

Therefore I can't use most keyboard shortcuts, and since it's a Spanish keyboard I can't even type some characters such as @ that require a combination with [alt-gr].

It's not the keyboard layout. I know I'm using the right one, the "eye" icon in Settings > Region & Language shows a distribution that matches what's actually printed on the keys. (That window actually helped me pinpoint the key subtitutions I'm getting). I tried changing it anyway, only to check that the problem remains.

The problem was not present when I tried plugging another keyboard.
So I believe it must be something about the keyboard itself. I know it's not broken because it works in windows. Perhaps a driver or something.

The keyboard brand and model is: Noga, NKB-380A

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, open Terminal and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` bring this keyboard choice menu, select either Logitech or Logitech Ultra-X or Logitech Access, I guess it is one of them. And if you succeeded then https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. I tried those three, and then some other random choices from that menu, so far no luck.
Thanks for answering.

Comment: wow this is really surprising. I have tried so many keyboard, none works like that. Have you also tried `xev` from terminal and confirmed that all modifier keys are registering `Shift`?

Comment: Just tried `xev`, and it registers `Shift_L` on all involved keys

Comment: Did you try this keyboard plug into another computer without drivers? or ask Noga? `xev` tells each keys are different; then you can asign them by `xmodmap` https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-can-i-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04