# Latin american keyboard layout not detected on i3

Tags: 22.04, i3-wm

In previous ubuntu versions, during the installation process, I selected English language and the latin american keyboard layout. When installing i3, it worked as expected.

On 22.04:

- When using the default desktop environment (Gnome 42, I believe), it works as intended.
- [*This is the problem*] When using i3, the keyboard changes from spanish (latin american) to english and I haven't figured out how to change

Here is the locale output, in case it helps.

```sh
➜ % locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

All locales are available, any suggestions on what's going on here or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure your keyboard at a deeper level with the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout
```

That will preserve the configuration in the Ubuntu desktop, which has its own configuration layer for the keyboard layout.

Comment: I couldn't find the `keyboard-layout` package, based on this suggestion I tried:

    sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration


but it had no effect neither in current session nor after a reboot.

Comment: Also, I tried [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard) but after comparing the files, the `/etc/default/keyboard` in my 20.04 host machine (working as intended) has the same contents as the file in the 22.04 VB guest machine (not working as intended).