# How to specify in password input dialog the language always to be English?

Tags: gnome, password

In Gnome I often enter sudo password when Russian language is being selected. It's so annoying to wait for password verification fail, to switch to English and retype the password!

Is there a way to force English in password input dialog? Especially on logon screen.

Comment: That's an interesting question, but it probably requires a code change.  I can't see a developer thinking about that one coming.  Upvote from me anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using gsettings

**It works well with Gnome/Unity Indicator/Layout switch on Ubuntu 13.10 or later.**

Run `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` to check your active layouts and input systems.

**Problems**:

In lock dialog case, it is unable to restore last used keyboard. So after unlock always `en`

- **For sudo** (Alias)

  ```
  nano ~/.bashrc
  ```

  Append this line

  ```
  alias sudo="sudo_success='' ; last_kbd=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current | awk '{print $2}'` ; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0 ; sudo echo -n  && sudo_success='1' ; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $last_kbd ; test $sudo_success && sudo"
  ```
- **For lock dialog** (Proxy)

  ```
  cd /usr/lib/gnome-screensaver/
  sudo mv gnome-screensaver-dialog gnome-screensaver-dialog_orig
  sudo nano gnome-screensaver-dialog_proxy
  ```

  Put this in:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  last_kbd=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current | awk '{print $2}'`
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
  /usr/lib/gnome-screensaver/gnome-screensaver-dialog_orig $@
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $last_kbd
  ```

  Fix a link:

  ```
  sudo chown root:root gnome-screensaver-dialog_proxy
  sudo chmod +x root:root gnome-screensaver-dialog_proxy
  sudo ln -s gnome-screensaver-dialog_proxy gnome-screensaver-dialog
  ```

---

### Old answer using setxkbmap

**Use it, only if your layouts is set with `setxkbmap` command.**

Complete steps are mentioned above. I kept only different steps.
 I am using us,ara (English, Arabic), run `setxkbmap -query` to check yours.

**Problems**:

setxkbmap change layout at X level, which does override effective Unity/Gnome layout. Indicator keep showing last layout. Also it breaks some layout switching keyboard shortcuts. To avoid that add your shortcuts options to `setxkbmap` command. Example: `setxkbmap us,ara -option grp:rshift_toggle -option grp:rctrl_switch`.

In lock dialog case, it is unable to restore last used keyboard.

- **For sudo**

  ```
  nano ~/.bashrc
  ```

  Append this line

  ```
  alias sudo="sudo_success='' ; last_kbd=$(setxkbmap -query | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $2}') ; setxkbmap us,ara ; sudo echo -n && sudo_success='1' ; setxkbmap $last_kbd ; test $sudo_success && sudo"
  ```
- **For lock dialog**

  ```
  nano gnome-screensaver-dialog_proxy
  ```

  Put this in:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  last_kbd=$(setxkbmap -query | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $2}')
  setxkbmap us,ara
  /usr/lib/gnome-screensaver/gnome-screensaver-dialog_orig $@
  setxkbmap $last_kbd
  ```

Comment: That looks promising!

But it completely brokes switching laouts by shortcuts. 

I use CapsLock to switch between layouts, also I use xNeur to utilize LeftShift and RightShift for switching to us and ru layouts. But all these keys stop working after I set layout with setxkbmap (

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line , :) I should told you before to set an escape combination!