# Force lock screen password input to NOT use Japanese iBus IME

Tags: password, lock-screen, ibus, japanese, mozc

Since I upgraded my 2 laptops from 13.10 to 14.04, I sometimes have a problem entering password to exit lock screen:

When typing in the password field of the lock screen, I see that the usual dark dots appear underlined, only for 3 characters typed only 1 or 2 dots appear. That's a clear sign that Japanese IME has decided to kick in. It does not happen everytime.

I guess it is not a bug and some people really have passwords in Japanese, but personally I find it totally annoying.

How to disable Japanese IME for the password field?
Or just disable Japanese IME when the lock screen appears.

Comment: If you are using `gnome-screensaver` check this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/412856/how-to-specify-in-password-input-dialog-the-language-always-to-be-english/413536#413536 otherway, what do you have, is it default Unity desktop?

Comment: Yes, Unity, and I use the default screensaver.