# How do I change the language of the console permanently?

Tags: command-line, language-support

Is there a way I can change the language of the console? I have seen things such as adding `LANG=C` in front of the commands but that is a temporary fix.

I can live with the Turkish console but when it comes to `man` and `help` commands it drives me nuts. I do not understand the Turkish terms used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable input language switching in terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637148/how-to-disable-input-language-switching-in-terminal)

Comment: @Pilot6 that is not my problem. I want English to be my permanent language for the terminal. I don't want to switch my keyboard layout. So not a duplicate of (http://askubuntu.com/questions/637148/how-to-disable-input-language-switching-in-terminal)

Comment: You want to set a permanent  layout for *only* the terminal, which seems to me an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Pilot6: Input language and display language are two separate things!

Comment: @JacobVlijm Layout? I am talking about the language the terminal uses to output data to me. I am not talking about my keyboard layout. Just a  Menu+Space fixes that(altough I am used to Alt+Shift from windows).

Comment: Aaaahhh, I see. Now I understand, sorry, retracted my vote...

Comment: Retracted mine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command to save it in your `~/.bashrc` file so that every time you open an interactive non-login terminal your `locale` will be set accordingly:

```sh
echo 'export LANG=C' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Note that the `C` locale uses an ASCII character set, if you want Unicode then use a `locale` that supports it e.g.:

```sh
echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc
```

To make changes available from the running session, `source` the `~/.bashrc` file:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What about the login terminal? I really don't use the non-login terminal.

Comment: @utkumaden In case of login interactive terminals, just replace `~/.bashrc` with `~/.profile`

Comment: @heemayl I think for most tasks that the user needs, `~/.bashrc` will be sufficient. It works for be in both ttys and graphical terminal,so . . .

Comment: @Serg `~/.bashrc` is for non-login shells..OP mentioned in the previous comment they use login shell..

Comment: I wish it would have worked. It did not.  I checked the non login terminal. It did work there. I might want to try @Serg 's answer for this.

Comment: @utkumaden can you give the exact command you have tried? also login terminal means consoles, are we right over there?

Comment: @heemayl Well I did `sudo gedit ~/.profile.` then added `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` at the end

Comment: @utkumaden no..no `sudo`..`sudo` means you are changing the `~/.profile` for root....just use `gedit ~/.profile` and add the line..also run `source ~/.profile` after that..

Comment: basically, you need to both add the line to the file and then update your shell with the `source` command

Comment: Even without `sudo`, it didn't work. Maybe it is because I screwed with it using `sudo`.  I don't know what to do. And no, I did not stack `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` over each other.  I will try removing the lines using `sudo` then if the lines are still present in .profile I will remove it form there too. Then follow these instructions as is. I will return if I get anymore problems.

Comment: And as I guessed nothing happened. I will have to live with it then. Dang linux, this is one thing that puts me off from linux.

Comment: @utkumaden if you are using `sudo` you are changing `.profile` of root, not the normal user..i am not clear what changes you have made actually..although changing the `~/.profile` is the ideal way, just saving it in `~/.bashrc` would do as `~/.profile` has a stanza to `source` the `~/bashrc` from it..but this not the right way to put non-login shells stuffs in `~/.bashrc` because not all shells has the stanza and anyone can remove that stanza to keep a different envitonment for two cases..remove the entries you have added to `~/.profile`, run the commands i have given with `~/.profile`

Comment: @utkumaden on a different note, try `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` instead as `LC_ALL` takes predence over them all....

Comment: @heemayl: It does not take precedence over the LANGUAGE variable, which is what needs to be changed, unless LANG or LC_ALL is set to C.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I did not know that..also `man bash` and `man locale` do not have it..could you please share a reference..

Comment: @heemayl: It's a [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html) thing.

Answer (score 0):

Put that into your `~/.bashrc` file, where you define the prompt. Example:

`PS1='$(LANG=C)serg@ubuntu $ '`

Comment: Were exactly does that line go? I can't find where I am supposed to add it.

Comment: So, basically in your homefolder, you can create `.bashrc ` file, which is read by bash every time you open terminal. For example, I use it to define my prompt as `PS1=' serg@ubuntu  ' `. If I want a command to be run there every time I open terminal or run something in terminal, I add `$( command )` to that PS1='serg@ubuntu' line, just like i showed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file in my `~/bin` folder to get gnome-terminal in English:

```
$ cat ~/bin/gnome-terminal
#!/bin/sh
export LANGUAGE=en_US
exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal $@
```

(`~/bin` is the first item in $PATH if it exists)

Please note that since the LANGUAGE variable is set more often than not in Ubuntu, and since gnome-terminal uses gettext, it's LANGUAGE which needs to be changed, not LANG.