# Disable switch-applications(Alt+Tab) using shell script or python in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, python, shortcut-keys

[How can I disable Alt-Tab application switching in Cinnamon when a certain program is open?](https://askubuntu.com/a/638757/773499)
**In System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**
Tried to disable, click on it to set a new shortcut, then pressing Backspace to set disable that shortcut.

**Using gsettings commands**
The keybindings to switch to another workspace are set in:

org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications []
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-background []
```

I have tried these many methods to disable alt+tab key but still not disabled. Maybe I need to set it globally but in ubuntu where alt+tab key values  stored, I don't known. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change it with `dconf` (from `dconf-cli` package):

```
dconf load / << EOF 
[org/compiz]
current-profile='unity'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell]
alt-tab-prev='Disabled'
launcher-switcher-prev='Disabled'
alt-tab-forward='Disabled'
launcher-switcher-forward='Disabled'
alt-tab-forward-all='Disabled'
alt-tab-prev-all='Disabled'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/switcher]
prev-all-key='Disabled'
prev-key='Disabled'
next-all-key='Disabled'
next-key='Disabled'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/staticswitcher]
prev-all-key='Disabled'
next-all-key='Disabled'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx/plugins/unityshell]
alt-tab-prev='Disabled'
launcher-switcher-prev='Disabled'
alt-tab-forward='Disabled'
launcher-switcher-forward='Disabled'
alt-tab-forward-all='Disabled'
alt-tab-prev-all='Disabled'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx/plugins/switcher]
prev-all-key='Disabled'
prev-key='Disabled'
next-all-key='Disabled'
next-key='Disabled'

[org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx/plugins/staticswitcher]
prev-all-key='Disabled'
next-all-key='Disabled'
EOF
```

**Notes:**

1. this will disable all occurrences of <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.
2. on my VirtualBox 16.04 LTS has two Compiz profiles - *unity* and *unity-lowgfx*. If you are sure that you have only *unity* you can skip *unity-lowgfx*.

You can revert to default settings with

```
dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx -f
dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity -f
```

then logout and login again.

Comment: I tried the above code but still issue remains. Please let me know alternatives ways to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer. It was not too simple.

Comment: Great !! It works fine.

Comment: Do not forget to vote and accept it if it helped :)

Comment: dconf load / << EOF 

[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
show-desktop='Disabled'
maximize='Disabled'
unmaximize='Disabled'
EOF.   I have tried this. should I try it for unity-lowgfx? Please suggest on this.

Comment: I was testing this on VirtualBox, it spontaneously switches between profiles. On real hardware you do not need  `unity-lowgfx` profile I think.

Comment: @Norbert , is it possible to unload above dconf command permanently from the dconf database

Comment: I think you should use `dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx -f` and `dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity -f`.

Comment: I do not understand. The above two commands will remove our custom settings from `dconf`. You can consult `dconf help reset` for details.