# Disabling the `Alt-Tab` Keyboard Shortcut when a certain app is active?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I know that I'm able to disable (and even change) the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> window switching shortcut through Ubuntu's settings menu. However, what I'd like to do is keep it for all but a certain application.

Is there a way to conditionally disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> when that application is open? Or some way I can rig a script together to do approximately this?

---

**EDIT:** The specific application I want Alt-Tabbing disabled for is `godot`. The following script (from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638538/how-can-i-disable-alt-tab-application-switching-in-cinnamon-when-a-certain-progr?rq=1)) fails to work on my machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

keySwitchApplication="switch-applications"
keySwitchApplicationBackward="switch-applications-backward"

backupSwitchApplications="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplication")"
disableSwitchApplications="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplication" | sed "s/\,*\s*'<Alt>Tab'//")"

backupSwitchApplicationsBackward="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplicationBackward")"
disableSwitchApplicationsBackward="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplicationBackward" | sed "s/\,*\s*'<Shift><Alt>Tab'//")"

disabled="0"

while true; do
  isActive=$(wmctrl -lx | awk -v search=$(printf 0x0%x $(xdotool getactivewindow)) -v wm_class="$wm_class" '{ if($1 ~ search && $3 ~ /godot/) print $3 }')

  if [[ "$isActive" != "" ]]; then
    # echo "active"
    if [[ "$disabled" == "0" ]]; then
      # echo "disable shortcut"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplication" "$disableSwitchApplications"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplicationBackward" "$disableSwitchApplicationsBackward"
      disabled="1";
    fi
  else
    # echo "not active"
    if [[ "$disabled" == "1" ]]; then
      # echo "enable shortcut"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplication" "$backupSwitchApplications"
      gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings "$keySwitchApplicationBackward" "$backupSwitchApplicationsBackward"
      disabled="0"
    fi;
  fi;
  sleep 1
done
```

In fact just simply calling

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['']"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['']"
```

fails to disable Alt-Tabbing in Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Do you mean that Alt+Tab should be totally disabled when that application is running (or its window is in focus) or do you just want that application (or its windows) not to appear in the task switcher?

Comment: @DKBose: The former

Comment: If https://askubuntu.com/questions/638538/how-can-i-disable-alt-tab-application-switching-in-cinnamon-when-a-certain-progr?rq=1 meets your requirements, you can close the current question as a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @DKBose: That post is topical but for some reason the solution provided doesn't work on my machine. See my edited response above.