# Remembering Guake keyboard layout

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, guake

I use the Guake terminal a lot and one thing really bothers me. I use two keyboard layouts (Czech and English) and I often switch between one another in a way that every window has its layout (i.e. not one global layout but a per-window layout). Typically I have English layout where I do programming, etc. and Czech layout in empathy chat windows, etc. However, Guake is out of this system - it does not remember its layout and picks the layout off the last active window before Guake is called to appear. This really annoys me since each time I have different layout, depending on what I was doing before.

Is there any way to make Guake remember its keyboard layout? Thanks for any hints.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 with Gnome shell 3.14.4 and Guake 0.5.0.

Here are my settings:
[image: Layout settings]

Comment: How did you configure the behavior?

Comment: @A.B. I didn't do any special configuration. I just have two input sources set in Settings -> Region & Language and "Allow different sources for each window" selected in the input source options. I'll edit the question with an image in a while.

Comment: @JanŽegklitz I've written a script before that forces a specific language per application. Refer here http://askubuntu.com/q/655628/295286  Let me know if you need help editing the script  or anything else.

Comment: @Serg Thanks, I'll give it a try, but I have doubts. I really need the language to be set per window because per application is not enough for me - e.g. in Chrome I typically use english in the main browser window, but in hangouts window I typically use czech as I speak with my czech friends. And sometimes I have more browser windows as well.

Comment: @JanŽegklitz  There's certainly ways to make language setting work per window, as each window has unique hexadecimal id associated with it, so we could assing language based on hexadecimal id. But these hexadecimal ids aren't static, they change as windows are closed or open. I'd suggest you use two different browsers - one associated with language A and the other with language B. I'll let you know if I come up with something else

Comment: @Serg Don't bother too much, it's just annoying, not a show-stopper :). And it's really just about Guake as I think about it...