# German Umlauts on an English keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3-wm

I switched to the American keyboard layout mainly because I find it easier to program that way. But for other applications I sometimes need umlauts.

I tried using the US international layout but the position for the umlauts is just strange and it wasn't as good for programming as well.

Can I configure my i3wm to have custom keyboard shortcuts for that? Something like holding <kbd>o</kbd> or pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> will yield `ö`.

Comment: I don't think Umlaute is common sense. Try to describe it like special characters.

Comment: why not do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/655628/assign-default-keyboard-language-per-application

Comment: I don't like switching between layouts all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ArchLinux wiki has [an answer that worked for me with i3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Configuring_compose_key). You can use the *compose key* to achieve typing any kind of Unicode character. I have a UK layout, but often need to type German characters. With the compose key, I can type `CapsLock` then `"` then `a` to get `ä`.

First, find which compose options are available

```
grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

This should give you something along the lines of:

```
...
compose:menu         Menu
compose:caps         Caps Lock
...
```

Then set your compose key to the preferred key. I'm using caps lock for that.

```
setxkbmap -option compose:caps
```

If you can't find a suitable pre-defined configuration for the compose key, I think you'll have to set up your own [xmodmap configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to install the [autokey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) app:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

and configure your shortcuts for the umlauts. For the initial configuration you can copy them manually from the [characters](https://snapcraft.io/gnome-characters) app.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). After having done so, you can for instance type ö by pressing this sequence:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by " followed by o

Comment: Could you please add the relevant information on how to enable the *Compose* key to your answer? As it is, this is mostly a link-only answer. Furthermore, the link is not even that helpful as it only describes how to enable *Compose* in GNOME, whereas the question is specifically mentions and is tagged with `i3-wm`.

Comment: @Adaephon: The suggestion to enable a compose key is my answer. I consider how to do it to be another question, so the the link to the official Ubuntu documentation is a bonus. ;) I know nothing about `i3-wm`.