# Configuring compose key via command line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, i3-wm

I use i3 window manager and I'm trying to activate <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> as compose key to be able to type accented letters. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The answer from this question also applies here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/934878/i3-german-umlaute-on-on-english-keyboard?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `xmodmap`. Add the following to `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode 108 = Alt_R
keysym Alt_R = Multi_key
```