# How to set keyboard switch with Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, Ctrl+3 etc

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 15.04, keyboard-layout

In windows in keyboard switch settings there is an option that you can switch keyboard language with unique combination for each one.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - for english, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> - for russian, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> for ukrainian etc. 
It would be super handy, if there is an option to set this thing in Ubuntu.

Are there any options?

Comment: Read Sneetsher's answer from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line). Then you will be able to set custom shortcut from *keyboard settings*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `setxkbmap`. From `man setxkbmap`:

> The setxkbmap command maps the keyboard to use the layout determined
>   by the options specified on the command line.

To do this, open `Keyboard` from settings and click on `Custom Shortcuts`. Click on the `+` sign and add fill up the 'Custom Shortcut' windows as shown below:

[image]

Press Apply. Click on 'Disabled' and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to make this as a shortcut for enabling Russian.

Now repeat the steps, but add `setxkbmap us` as the command and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> as the shortcut. This will enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> as the shortcut for English

Comment: The problem is that it will not change the indicator in 14.04+.

Comment: You are right, but is that a major problem?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What's the output of `setxkbmap -query` after you've done Ctrl+2?

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly switch between your installed keyboard layout by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>space bar</kbd>.

For changing this keyboard shortcut go in :

```
System settings > Text Entry.
```

[image]
(sorry screenshot not in English)

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. I need those settings. Cause I'm using 4 languages.

Comment: Have you added your 4 languages in `Input sources to use` ?

Comment: it doesn't work to set combination for a certain language

Comment: it should be - ctrl+1 - switches to english. Ctrl+2 - switches to russian. Idk if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget! If you need to use English need print specific two symbols for different languages:

`setxkbmap us` - if you use us English

`setxkbmap uk` - if you use uk English
and so on