# How to set keyboard layout switching on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04) with "Ctrl+1" for "Language1", "Ctrl+2" for "Language2", etc

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04, wayland

How to set keyboard layout switching on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for `Language1`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for `Language2`, etc.

For exaple:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for `English`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for `French`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for `German`.

This question is already on this site ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655043/how-to-set-keyboard-switch-with-ctrl1-ctrl2-ctrl3-etc)), but the command has no effect on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04).

Please tell me how to do the same on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04).

One more thing: please make the instructions as simple as possible, because I am new to Linux. If the instruction is something like "decompile the Linux kernel and write some simple assembly language commands in it", I will definitely fail. Thus, please give me the easiest instruction possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set keyboard switch with Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, Ctrl+3 etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655043/how-to-set-keyboard-switch-with-ctrl1-ctrl2-ctrl3-etc)

Comment: There *is* setxkbmap working on Wayland, and it is by default installed on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @vanadium Thank you, but it does not work on my Ubuntu 22.04, see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/zJ3VEDC.jpg). The languages are only switched with Super+Space.

Comment: Indeed; I can confirm: the command has no effect on  Wayland. However, edit your question to change "But there is no setxkbmap on Wayland!" because the command is available in a default install.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for the tip. Sorry, I really did not know that setxkbmap is in Ubuntu 22.04. I thought the command did not work because Wayland does not have setxkbmap, but I was wrong. Sorry.