# Multi language input

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I use more than two layouts, and in Windows I use shortcuts ctrl+1, ctrl+2, etc. for different languages. Is it possible to implement something like this in Ubuntu? I suppose that I can create my own shortcuts, but what commands can be use then, I have not found yet.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, https://askubuntu.com/questions/655043/how-to-set-keyboard-switch-with-ctrl1-ctrl2-ctrl3-etc?rq=1