# Is it possible to use a custom keyboard layout without sudo access? If so, how?

Tags: sudo, keyboard-layout

I have been using a custom keyboard for a while, using the instructions detailed in the Help.Ubuntu tutorial [Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) and further explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu). I have grown quite fond of this keyboard, but I have recently started using a machine where I don't really have sudo access (or rather, I do have some amount of access, but it is really awkward).

So: is it possible to do an equivalent installation that is only for my user, and which does not rely on administrative privileges? More specifically, if it comes to installing specific packages I'm OK with that, but if it requires substituting files outside of my home directory it gets a lot harder.

Answer (score 7):

*A quick proper answer since I can't comment yet:*

As I [mentioned on your other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/669043), you'd create your layout files in your home directory (or somewhere else you have write permissions) as a local version of the XKB database directory tree:

```
$HOME/.config/xkb/
...
├── rules
│   ├── evdev-local
...
├── symbols
│   ├── my-fun-capslock-options
│   ├── my-US-Dvorak-layout
│   └── my-ZWERTY-layout
...
```

... and then use the `-I` option with `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap -I $HOME/.config/xkb \
  -rules evdev-local           \
  -layout my-ZWERTY-layout     \
  -option myZWERTY:option1,compose:menu,fun:caps_is_insert
```

Comment: In [the answer to the other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/480880) you do list the `.lst` file explicitly, but, not here — after some testing, it seems that  `evdev-local.lst` is actually necessary for `setxkbmap` (though `evdev-local.xml` is apparently not) — so I'd suggest adding it to the tree, here, in case somebody does not read your aforementioned other answer.  Btw, the other answer is really amazingly comprehensive!

Answer (score 4):

The underlying command for setting the keyboard is [`setxkbmap`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line) --- now, looking at its manual pages, it seems that it will read keyboard specification from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, so that you need to write your modified layout there --- system directory, root access needed.

**BUT**

I tried this:

```
strace setxkbmap nonexistant |& grep open
```

to look at what the command is doing, and look: (partial output)

```
open("/run/user/1153/gdm/Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("./rules/evdev-C.lst", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./rules/evdev.lst", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev-C.lst", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

so it *seems* that `setxkbmap` is also looking in the current directory for the file specification. So maybe (I have no time to test) if you copy all the relevant directory structure from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` in, say, `$HOME/myxkb` and then try to issue the command

```
setxbmap -model pc105 -layout myshiny -variant myvariant
```

or whatever it *may* work.

PD: the [arch help pages are useful, as ever](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_setxkbmap); a nice command that you can use to see what the keyboard you are using is composed from is this one:

```
[romano:~] % setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     es,us
variant:    standard_tlde,
options:    caps:none,compose:caps,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+es(standard_tlde)+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(none)+compose(caps)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+es(standard_tlde)+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(none)+compose(caps)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend this [guide](http://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2014/06/06/custom-keyboard/) if you just want to extend an existing keyboard layout.

Comment: Thank you. It was very easy and works perfectly. Note, however, `xkb_symbols "fr" { ... }` shall be `xkb_symbols "fr" { ... };` (the last semicolon is needed). Otherwise `xkbcomp` fails due to a syntax error.

Comment: +1, this is the only thing which works for me now. Before it just worked with  `setxkbmap -v xxx`. So at last I used this: `setxkbmap <layout-name> <option> -option -print | xkbcomp -I. - $DISPLAY` under `/usr/share/X11/xkb`. I put my layout xxx under `symbols` and modified `evdev.lst` file under `rules`. `option` is the word you put after `xkb_symbols` in `the xxx layout file.

Answer (score 3):

[The](https://askubuntu.com/a/896298/480880) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/480880) by quixotic, are complete, functional and probably what you should normally do. However, if you do not want to copy and modify the `rules` files, for whatever reason, here is an alternative solution.

In this case, we will be loading an "xkb keymap file", directly using `xkbcomp`.

First, create whatever custom layout or option you want, say in file `~/.config/xkb/symbols/option_file` with contents:

```
partial hidden modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "new_option_1" {
    [...]
};
```

Next, dump your current layout, using `setxkbmap -print > ~/.config/xkb/keymap/my_layout`. (Note that this does not, necessarily, have to be in the same directory hierarchy as the `symbols` file above (or any other files you add), as we will be specifying the path to it explicitly.) This will be something of the form of:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

To enable your new option, edit the dumped layout, by adding `+option_file(new_option_1)` to the `xkb_symbols` line, so our example would have become:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+option_file(new_option_1)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Finally, load the new keymap with: `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.config/xkb ~/.config/xkb/keymap/my_layout $DISPLAY`.

References:

http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/

https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.en.html

Comment: Sorry, but it expects `~/.config/xkb` file, which is nowhere to find.