# How do I install a keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a [keyboard layout file](http://aoeu.info/layouts/files/magnus-xkb-se) that I want to install on 17.10, but I fail to make it work.

How is it supposed to be done?

So far I have tried

- Guessing how to do it based on existing files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and the appearance of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`
- Guessing what a "variant" is, how to add it, what fields need to be updated, where the contents of this symbols file should be placed
- Guessing that placing it with a unique name directly in `/symbols/` means I have to add it as a `<layout>` in `evdev.xml`. Still no idea whether that is true, nor which field -- if any -- is supposed to correspond to the file name
- Guessing that placing it inside an existing file in `/symbols/` means I have to add it as a "variant". No idea whether that is true

It would help if there was some way to avoid the guessing. I don't need a crash-course in the architecture, just a non-ambiguous way to make the keyboard layout...

1. show up in the keyboard layout settings dialog, and...
2. produce the correct input

So far the farthest I've come is #1 -- but don't ask me how, because I don't know which part did it.

---

#### Update

Exactly this has been done

- The contents of the symbols file that I linked to is in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/svorak-a5`
- The following block has been inserted into `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` right before the pre-existing element sequence `<layout>` `<configItem>` `<name>se`:

  ```
   <layout>
     <configItem>
       <name>svorak-a5</name>

       <shortDescription>sva5</shortDescription>
       <description>Svorak A5</description>
       <languageList>
         <iso639Id>swe</iso639Id>
       </languageList>
     </configItem>
   </layout>
  ```
- `/var/lib/xkb` contains no `.xkm`s.

Comment: that is a `symbols` file (or part of one) for use with `xkb`; for users with X11 and tools like `setxkbmap` it can go almost anywhere, but for Wayland or systemwide it will need to be installed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.  see https://askubuntu.com/a/969232/669043

Comment: @quixotic It is already in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/svorak-a5`. I'm afraid I don't know how to adapt your answer there to proceed with subsequent steps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should give the layout variant a name; see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se` for examples. Then add it to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se` and add a corresponding entry to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`.

*Edit:*

I tested the steps in the "update" section of your question, and it worked fine for me after having rebooted. The layout is shown in a submenu of *Swedish (Sweden)*.

For testing subsequent changes, rebooting isn't necessary, but this command should suffice:

```
systemctl restart keyboard-setup
```

*Edit II:*

I have a theory (untested) on why the layout isn't working as robustly as you would wish. Try to change the two first lines in `svorak-a5`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "svorak" {
```

to

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68853/discussion-on-answer-by-gunnar-hjalmarsson-how-do-i-install-a-keyboard-layout).