# Add custom keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, 17.10, xkb

I have a custom keyboard layout that I want to add to Ubuntu 17.10. This question relates to [How do I install a keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976797/how-do-i-install-a-keyboard-layout) but unfortunate I'm not allowed to comment on that one. Basically I have done the same thing.

I have downloaded http://tlundqvist.org/sv_dvorak/drivers/se_sv_dvorak_new.xorg and saved it to */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se_sv_dvorak*

I have added below section to */usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml*

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>se_sv_dvorak</name>

    <shortDescription>svd</shortDescription>
    <description>Swedish dvorak</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>swe</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
</layout>
```

I have also added below section to */usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst*

```
se_sv_dvorak     Swedish dvorak
```

Then I have:

- sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
- systemctl restart keyboard-setup

I have also tried to reboot but when I go to *Settings -> Region & Language* and press *+* I can't find my new layout. What is wrong?

**EDIT 1:** This is what I can select:

- [Under ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taFMD.png)
- [Under other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAE1d.png)

**EDIT 2:** By running *sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration* I can change to right keyboard layout but that only works until I have logged in.

Comment: The menu item should be present in a sub menu of _Swedish (Sweden)_.

Comment: Yes it should but it is not. Have updated post with pictures.

Comment: I meant to say that you should click the _Swedish (Sweden)_ option to open the sub menu.

Comment: Doh! Didn't know you could do that! Then it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson OP reported that you comment solved it for him, would you submit it as an answer.