# Map Caps Lock to delete whole word

Tags: keyboard, xkb, capslock

I used dconf-editor to map caps lock to backspace, which works fine.
i.e. `['caps:backspace']`

But I'd like to map caps lock to ctrl_backspace, so that it deletes the whole word when pressed.

Is this possible?
I tried `['caps:ctrl_backspace']` but it doesn't work.

Comment: the entries in that list are specific xkb options (see `man xkeyboard-config` for a list).  `caps:ctrl_backspace` is not one of these options, hence the not working.  you would have to add it: see eg https://askubuntu.com/a/969232/669043