# Remap Caps Lock key to Ctrl+Y or other key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, capslock

I am trying to remap my caps lock key to a new key combination like ctrl+b for using tmux. I spent hours googling but all explanations are just cryptic or only cover remapping a key to only a single other key and not a key combination like ctrl+b.

I found this other post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968806/remap-caps-lock-to-ctrl-b) but once again the author asks how to remap to a key combination but only gets told how to remap to a single key. I am getting really desperate here.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve this? The man pages and all other posts in this forum or anything I found through Google was useless to me. I would be really grateful for your help.

P.S.: Please do NOT post an answer telling me how to only remap a single key!!!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys The answer with 27 votes is probably the better option in my opinion but both do work.

Comment: Not useful if you read my post

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I finally found a solution. I first disabled the caps lock key in gnome tweaks and then installed [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

My script for pressing CTRL-y looks like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl_l)
keyboard.press('y')
keyboard.release('y')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl_l)
```