# Command to toggle keyboard layouts

Tags: kde

I write in french and I code in english. Is there a command to easily toggle between these two keyboard layout?

I could not find any other than setxkbmap or other similar command, but I would need to write a script to query current layout and depending on the layout, switch to the appropriate layout. Is there a better way?

Thanks!!

Comment: look to gsettings answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line

Comment: thank you, I did not found it, that answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle smoothly between two keyboard layouts with the help of some combination of keyboard keys:

- Key for go forward in layout list => <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
- Key for go backward in layout list => <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

If this don't work, check the following setting. If it's not setup, then set this according to the following steps:

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Region & Language in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the Input Sources section, select the language which is associated with the layout, then select a layout and
   press Add.

For more information you can take help of given link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't upvote because I don't have enought points for it. Super+space was not working because I use a tiling management, but this answer worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line.