# Keyboard configuration without X11

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm trying to configure an USB keyboard with br layout (brazilian portuguese) on Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS without X11 (running in a Raspberry pi 4).

I already tried these commands, no one worked:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
4. Manually editing `/etc/default/keyboard`
5. `sudo systemctl set-keymap br`

With `sudo loadkeys br`, it works, but it not persintent: I need to type this everytime I reboot the system.

Content of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105" 
XKBLAYOUT="br"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Content of `/etc/vconsole.conf`:

```
KEYMAP=br
```

Any help?

ps: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line) they suggest to use `setxkbmap` (which requires X) or other solutions with Gnome. Also, to put `loadkeys br` in `.bashrc` should work, but is it relly the only option?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line) help? or put `loadkeys br` into `.bashrc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change keyboards from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @vanadium @sadaharu-wakisaka they are suggesting to use `setxkbmap` (which requires X, I'm trying to avoid this) or `loadkeys` (not persistent).  Until now to put in `.bashrc` seems to be my only option :-(

Comment: I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `loadkeys br` in /etc/profile

It's already running as root, you don't need a sudo.