# keyboard layout switching doesn't work in 13.10

Tags: keyboard-layout, 13.10

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu into 13.10.
Now I can't use classical keyboard layout switching (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>).
I can't even change with settings:

[image]

New interface doesn't save my combination (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>).

How I can change it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed at [Switch to specific keyboard layout using Ctrl+Shift+Num](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201677/switch-to-specific-keyboard-layout-using-ctrlshiftnum?rq=1) that you can use Ctrl + Shift + 1 to switch to an English keyboard layout.

Comment: In my Ubuntu ctrl+shift+1 is screenshot :) screencloud app )

Answer (score 0):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1218322.

You can enable proposed updates in Synaptic and you will get updated packages for layout switching.