# Ubuntu 14.04: language switch between first/last source

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, language-support, ibus

In older versions of Ubuntu I used to switch between languages using last/first sources (e.g. `Caps Lock` always turn on English and `Shift + Caps Lock` switches to Russian, no matter what current language is).

But in 14.04 I can see only `next/previous source` options. Is there any way to set up good old last/first source switch?

Answer (score 1):

Has there really been a feature for switching between first and last source? To be honest I doubt it.

IBus has a feature for triggering and 'untriggering' the set input method, but it's disabled in later Ubuntu versions. Possibly that's what you are referring to.

As far as I know, in Ubuntu 14.04 you need to use some other IM framework, e.g. fcitx, to achieve exactly the behavior you describe.

Comment: I used it no later than 2 days ago in 13.04, so I'm really sure there was a feature like this.

Comment: And yes, probably installing other IM framework will help, but I don't know which one and how to configure it. That's why I'm here.

Comment: @uncleLem: The triggering thing was present in 13.04, and that feature let you easily select English (without input method) or Russian (with input method). I just don't think it was designed to pick "first" and "last" source. As regards some other framework, I'd recommend fcitx since it is actively maintained. If you would try it and encounter problems, that would be another question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsettings` command with custom shortcuts to switch with a hot key to any layout you want. Read more details here: https://askubuntu.com/a/984981/6193