# How to configure shortcuts to switch to specific keyboard layout in ubuntu 14

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I use 3 different languages and the standard way to switch between them one by one is not convenient (I need to remember the current language and check how many times I have to click the switch combination). In Windows I have a possibility to assign Alt+Shift+1 for English, Alt+Shift+2 for Russian, Alt+Shift+0 for Hebrew.
Is this possible to configure Ubuntu 14 for the same shortcuts?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Keyboard layout in Xorg server session can be easily changed via `setxkbmap`.

Usage is pretty simple. Just pass your locale as an argument for that command and your current input would be changed (works both for console apps and for UI apps):

```
SYNOPSIS
   setxkbmap [ args ] [ layout [ variant [ option ...  ] ] ]
```

The call you need is: `setxkbmap us`. Or you may need more options which you can grab by running `setxkbmap -query` while you are on some locale.

So to have your request done:

> Alt+Shift+1 for English, Alt+Shift+2 for Russian, Alt+Shift+0 for Hebrew

you'd need to assign following commands to [keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html):

- Alt+Shift+0 : `setxkbmap he`
- Alt+Shift+1 : `setxkbmap us`
- Alt+Shift+2 : `setxkbmap ru`

Comment: The language widget does not notice changes, but `setxkbmap` works nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such feature.

The answer I wrote to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526998/ubuntu-14-04-language-switch-between-first-last-source) might help. I.e. by switching to fcitx you might use fixed shortcuts for two of the inpput methods.