# How to change Layout Switching shortcuts separately?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I want to set Shortcut for  my next input source to ctrl+space , but have the "Switch to Previous source" disabled.

Right now as soon as I edit one of the shorcuts, the other one gets changed.

How do I achieve what I need?

Tried these, didn't help:
[Switch to specific keyboard layout using Ctrl+Shift+Num](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201677/switch-to-specific-keyboard-layout-using-ctrlshiftnum/984981#984981)

P.S. Using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: One way is to disable the shortcut keys completly for switching and bind a script to same shortcut that switches the language

Comment: Scripts in this post are for your idea.. You can tweak as you wish https://askubuntu.com/a/1198150/739431

Comment: Are you using standard Ubuntu or some other Ubuntu flavor, and if the latter, which one?

Comment: Answer indeed depends on the desktop environment you use, stock Ubuntu (Gnome Shell) or another flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it myself in *Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Typing* and can confirm your observation. Somehow the UI makes the previous shortcut depend on the next shortcut. Not sure if it's a bug or a feature.

OTOH, does it matter much? I mean, if you don't want to use the previous shortcut, then don't. You don't really need to disable it, do you?

Otherwise, if you really want to do it, you can first set the next shortcut and then run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "[]"
```

Comment: I want to use ctrl+space as my source switching Shortcut. It adds Ctrl+shift+space as the alternative. This means that I my shortcuts in iNtelliJ don't wor kcos they use ctrl+shift

Comment: Yup. This works. Thank you very much.